# Noise variance estimation under known channel

Tags: estimation, homework

I have $N$ observations $\{y_i\}_{i=1..N}$
$$y_i = h_i x_i + w_i$$
where $\{x_i\}_i$ are the realizations of uniform distributed QPSK symbol $x$, i.e. $x_i \in \{\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \pm j\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\}$,

$\{w_i\}_i$ are the realizations of circular complex gaussian noise $w \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma^2)$,

and $\{h_i\}_i$ are the realizations of random variable $h$, but known (for example via perfect channel estimation of a channel that is static during the duration that spans over $N$ observations).

The random variables $x$ and $w$ are i.i.d. ($h$ is known during the observation duration.)

**I want to estimate the noise variance $\sigma^2$.**

I tried using $\{\frac{y_i}{h_i}\}_i$ but their variances are scaled by $h_i$ and not be the same anymore.

Any hints?

(well, this is not a homework but maybe it is as simple as a homework for some people. So I keep the homework tag.)

---

Update: Note that the $N$ values $y_i$ are realizations, not random variables, for the desired $\sigma^2$ estimator.

Let me express my question in another way: I have $N$ values $y_i$ and $N$ values $h_i$, and I am looking for a function $f()$ that $\hat{\sigma}^2 = f(y_1,...,y_N,h_1,...,h_N)$.

So, $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is an estimation of $\sigma^2$, and is a random variable. It would be great that expected value of $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is $\sigma^2$ so that the estimator is unbiased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All $x_i$ are identically distributed: discretely uniformly distributed, with the only values being $\{-\sqrt{\frac12}, \sqrt{\frac12}\}$ on both the real and imaginary part.

The $w_i$ are also identically distributed, as per the problem statement.

Therefore, the variance (this being zero-mean) is simply $\sqrt{\frac12}^2=\frac12$ in each of the real and imaginary part.

For the $\mathcal CN$ noise: it has, by definition, indep. real and imaginary part, and their variances are $\frac{\sigma^2}2$ each. Since $h_i$ is known, knowing $\text{Var}(y_i)$ is as good as knowing $\sigma^2$: $\sigma^2 = \text{Var}(y_i) - \frac{h_i^2}2$.

Now, Cath claims that $y_i$ are not IID random variables but realizations of a stoch. process, but such realizations *are* random variables.

So, $h_ix_i$ and $w_i$ are independent. Meaning that the variance of their sum is just the sum of their variances, $\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}$

\begin{align}
\Var(y_i) &= h_i^2\Var(x_i) + \Var(w_i)\\
&= h_i^2\Var(x_i) + \sigma^2 \quad \|\Var(\Re\{ x_i\}) = \Var(\Im \{x_i\})= \frac 12\,\text{const.}\\
\Var(\Re \{y_i\})&=(\Re \{h_i\})^2\Var(\Re\{ x_i\})+(\Im \{h_i\})^2\Var(\Im \{x_i\}) + \frac{\sigma^2}2\\
&=\frac12\left(\Re \{h_i\})^2+(\Im \{h_i\})^2\right) + \frac{\sigma^2}2\\
&= \frac{\lvert h_i \rvert^2+\sigma^2}{2}
\\
&=\Var(\Im \{y_i\}) \quad \text{(symmetry)}\\[1em]
\Var{\sum_{i=1}^N \Re\{y_i\}} &= \frac12\left(
\sum_{i=1}^N\lvert h_i\rvert^2+ N\sigma^2
\right)\\
\sigma^2&=\frac{2\Var{\sum_{i=1}^N \Re\{y_i\}}-\sum_{i=1}^N\lvert h_i\rvert^2}{N},
\end{align}

same for the imaginary part of $y$. Now, that reads like a very usable approach for an estimator, right?

Comment: OK got it. So the estimator is $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \left( \mid y_i \mid^2 - \sigma_x^2 \mid h_i \mid^2\right) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \left( \mid y_i \mid^2 - \mid h_i \mid^2\right)$ as $\sigma_x^2 = 1$.

Comment: And it is unbiased.

Answer (score 0):

> Any hints?

sure!

## hint 1

You can easily estimate the variance of $y_i$.

## hint 2  & 2.5

You know the variance of $h_ix_i$ (hint: what does scaling with a scalar do to the variance of $x_i$?).

## hint 3

What is the variance of a sum of random variables that are independent?

Comment: Thanks. However, how can I estimate the variance of $y_i$? Do you mean by the sample variance estimator of $y$? Is it something like $var(y) = \frac{1}{N-1} \sum (y_i - \hat{\mu}_y)^2$ where $\hat{\mu}_y$ is the sample mean of $y$? But $\{y_i\}_i$ are not i.i.d.

Comment: Strictly speaking,$\{y_i\}_i$ are realizations, not random variables.

Comment: Maybe my wording was not clear. I have edited my question.

Comment: @Cath Maillon: Hi. You know the variance of the first term on the RHS. It's $h_t^2 \times$ the variance of a uniform. I think variance of a uniform (a,b) is $(a-b)^2/12$ but look it up. You can estimate the variance of $y_i$ as you described. Then, since the right hand side variances are additive, this means that $\hat\sigma^2 =  $ variance of $y_i$ minus the variance of the first term on the right hand side.  Note that the $y_i$ are iid because they are the sum of two iid terms. a normal rv and a uniform rv.

Comment: @markleeds very close! it's a uniform, but not a continuously distributed uniform; the variance as always is $\mathbb E(|x_i - \mathbb E(x_i)|^2)$, and $\mathbb E(x_i)=0$. However, it's easier to consider real and imaginary parts separate and then add them in the end – they're independent!

Comment: @Marcus Muller: Maybe you can address below because it needs fixing. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds : please remember that the $N$ values $y_i$ are realizations, not random variables, for the desired $\sigma^2$ estimator. They are random variables when we analyze the characteristics, e.g. bias, variance, Cramer bound, of the estimator. Let me express my question in another way: I have $N$ values $y_i$ and $N$ values $h_i$, and I am looking for a function $f()$ that $\hat{\sigma}^2 = f(y_1,...,y_N,h_1,...,h_N)$.

Comment: So, $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is an estimation of $\sigma^2$, and *is a random variable*. I would be great that the expected value of $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is $\sigma^2$ so that the estimator is unbiased.

Comment: @CathMaillon exactly, these are N realizations, from which you estimate $\sigma_y$. So, from your model it's defined tht $\mathbb E(y) \equiv 0$, you don't have to estimate. Therefore, the mean square of $y_i$, i.e. $\hat\sigma_y = \frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2$; and, as mark has already explained, $\sigma^ = \sigma^2_y - \frac1N\sum_{i=1}h_i^2\sigma^2_{x_i}$; since all $x_i$ have the same variance, the second summand simplifies to $\sigma_x^2 \sum_{i=1}^N h_i^2$. This means your $f(\ldots)=\frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2 - \frac1N\sigma_x^2\sum_{i=1}^N h_i^2$. Not really exciting!

Comment: Cath: I see your problem and I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that the var on the LHS is a sum because, since it's a sum, how does one estimate it. ( I have things wrong as far as the uniform variance but that's not the crucial issue ).  I'll read your comments and  Marcus' answer later on tonight and see if I follow any better. Definitely I spoke to soon and do see the problem that the $y_i$ depend on $i$ so we can't just estimate using the sample variance. My mistake.  Hopefully Marcus did something to fix that.

Comment: @markleeds I got it. The approach of Marcus is right and the said-estimator is what I am looking for. Just write down the expected value of the estimator and you will see.

Comment: @Cath Maillon: I follow the steps of Marcus' derivation. ( except for the var of uniform but I'll worry about that later. I'm not used to complex uniforms ). But then how did you go from Marcus's expression to the expression for  your unbiased estimator. Thanks.

Comment: @Marcus Muller: Nice derivation. But I have a confusion ( so comment above is not totally true ).  In the end, you write an expression for $\sigma^2$. But doesn't the sum of the Var term on the RHS of the expression have $\sigma^2$ in it ? Thanks.

Comment: No, not as far as I can tell?

Answer (score 0):

Let me write it here because the comment isn't that all that clear. You have

$Var(y_{i}) = (h_{i}^{2} \times (b-a)^2/12) + \sigma^2$

From the data, you will have, the sample observations, ${y_{i}}$.

You know the mean of the right hand side. Check it but I think it's zero.

So, given that the mean is zero, this implies that

$ \sum var(y_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}  [ h_{i}^2 \times (a-b)^2/12 +  \sigma^2 ]$.

So, now you can pull the second one out of the sum and treat it as $N \sigma^2$. Then, you can solve for $\sigma^2$ by bringing the sum of the other terms over to the LHS and then dividing by $N$.

EDIT: This answer is wrong because the LHS is a sum so how to estimate that ?  As far as I can tell, the OP is correct and the $h_i$ needs to be eliminated somehow so that the LHS can become $var(y)$ rather than $var(y_{i})$.

Comment: I have added some argument to make my question clearer in my question and in the MarcusMuller's answer.

Comment: Mark, you're assuming $x$ is *continuously uniformly* distributed, but it's discretely uniformly distributed, with the only values being $\{-\sqrt{\frac12}, \sqrt{\frac12}\}$ on both the real and imaginary part. Therefore, the variance (this being zero-mean) is simply $\sqrt{\frac12}^2=\frac12$ in each of the real and imaginary part. Same for the $\mathcal CN$ noise: it has, by definition, indep. real and imaginary part, and their variances are $\frac{\sigma^2}2$ each. Since $h_i$ is known, knowing $\text{Var}(y_i)$ is as good as knowing $\sigma^2$: $\sigma^2 = \text{Var}(y_i) - \frac{h_i^2}2$

Comment: Let me put all this in an answer.